# Deleting Answers on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I noticed a pretty unfixable error in one of my answers today and thus went to delete it. However, on the Android mobile app, the only options were to share, edit, or flag the post (no deletion). Would it be possible to add the delete option to posts as well on the mobile app?

Comment: You don't see a "delete" icon directly beneath your answer? I also have an android mobile, and I can see and use the delete function. Are you logged on? Could you post a screenshot, please?

Comment: @Mari-Lou this is about the android app, not mobile view in a browser.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, how does one switch from an app to mobile view?

Comment: @Mari-LouA more --> open in browser (inside a question)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ahh... inside the *question*, not an naswer, which is a bit annoying. Why not on the page itself? But now I see it :)